# vue js - change button of row after Ajax response

Tags: vue.js

[see the attachement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWIoc.png)

I have records populated and having a **following** button on each row which has `v-on:click="unfollow(dynamic_value)"`

I want to change the button to 'Follow' after the click and on successful Ajax response like

I have no idea how to do that in vue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you create a component for your records (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

You could create a component for each record with  a boolean named "followed" in the data of your component and on the v-on:click directive write a ternary condition where both methods would make an ajax call and on the success callback it would change the state of the boolean.

```
 Vue.component('follow-btn', {
  template: '#follow-btn-template',
  data: function () {
    return {
      followed: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    follow: function (dynamic_value) {
      // Ajax call and on success => change this.followed to true
    },
    unfollow: function (dynamic_value) {
      // Ajax call and on success => change this.followed to false
    }
  }
})
```

:

```
<script id='follow-btn-template' type="text/x-template">
  <button v-on:click="followed ? unfollow(dynamic_value) : follow(dynamic_value)">
    {{followed ? 'Following' : 'Follow'}} 
  </button>
</script>
```

or use a conditional directive

```
<script id='follow-btn-template' type="text/x-template">
  <button v-if="followed" v-on:click="unfollow(dynamic_value)"> Following</button>
  <button v-else v-on:click="follow(dynamic_value)"> Follow</button>
</script>
```

For the ajax call you either use jQuery, vue-resource or Axios.